# Configure the location of .coverage file when using /Enablecodecoverage in vstest.console.exe via command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, vstest

Is there a way to set the location of where the *.coverage* file would be located if we set `/Enablecodecoverage` in **vstest.console.exe**?

I did not see an option in the command line call itself. Is it to be set in the *.runsettings* file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in [General Command Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) that `/Enablecodecoverage` uses default settings if setting file is not specified.

---

> I did not see an option in the command line call itself. Is it to be set in the .runsettings file?

Yes, you have to [customize your .runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx) applies whenever you use **Analyze Code Coverage**.

- To customize run settings in a command line test

  - Launch the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt:

    On Windows **Start**, **choose All Programs**, **Microsoft Visual Studio**, **Visual Studio Tools**, **Developer Command Prompt**.
  - Run:

    ```
    vstest.console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll /EnableCodeCoverage /Settings:CodeCoverage.runsettings
    ```
- To customize run settings in a build definition

  You can get code coverage data from a team build.
  [image]
  **Note:** Make sure your .runsettings file is checked in.

---

### Edit:

[vstest.console.exe](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools#vstestconsoleexe) by default creates a *.coverage file, then the file can be converted to *.xml format.

To get the *.coverage file you can use the following command:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "PATH_OF_YOUR_EXECUTABLE_OR_DLL" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage

Create a new command line project in Visual Studio and add a reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll`.

Add the following code (paths are hard coded here, but could be supplied as arguments):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis;

namespace CoverageConverter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(
                "PATH_OF_YOUR_*.coverage_FILE", 
                new string[] { @"DIRECTORY_OF_YOUR_DLL_OR_EXE"}, 
                new string[] { }))
            {
                CoverageDS data = info.BuildDataSet();
                data.WriteXml("converted.coveragexml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CodeCoverage.exe is another coverage tool to convert into *.xml format [read more](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools#codecoverageexe).

### Edit 2:

You can use the `/UseVsixExtensions` option with `/EnableCodeCoverage` option to enable code coverage:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
 \Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
 /UseVsixExtensions:true /EnableCodeCoverage "C:\Users\YourName\Documents\Visual Studio
 2012\Projects\YourProjectFolder\YourApp.Tests\bin\Debug\YourApp.Tests.dll"
```

Above command will generate the .coverage file under the directory **TestResults**.

Comment: Definitely a lot of helpful information here, and a big start. What I was really hoping to do was to control the exact name and path of the output .coverage file, i.e. no date/time or guid, in order to use it as an input for further processing. Seems like otherwise, I need to get that path by parsing the test output.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch sorry for late reply see the **Edit** and **Edit 2** in the answer.

Comment: @AsifAli72090 Thanks for **Edit2**. I am using vstest.console.exe `Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.8.0`, which reports `/UseVsixExtensions is getting deprecated. Please use /TestAdapterPath instead`. Is there other way to generate the .coverage fiel under the directory **TestResults**, instead of the subdircectory like `TestResults\c193b54b-d7fe-4617-9b4c-0fafd541bcd6`

Answer (score 7):

You can change the name with a `CoverageFileName` node in a runsettings file and I believe set the output location with a `ResultsDirectory` node like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CoverageFileName>myname.coverage</CoverageFileName>
          <CodeCoverage>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Then run from command line:

```
vstest.console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll /EnableCodeCoverage /Settings:myrunsettings.runsettings
```

*Note: I would appreciate if someone could test that as I don't have Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and as of 2019, Enterprise is required to gather code coverage (it was available previously due to a bug).*

Comment: Some additional context: ResultsDirectory and CoverageFileName can also be specified from the command line. This is useful if you need unique values for downstream processing. Example: vstest.console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll /ResultsDirectory:"MyTestAssemblyResults" /EnableCodeCoverage /Settings:myrunsettings.runsettings -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.CoverageFileName="MyTestAssembly_Coverage.xml"

(See more info here: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1957)

Answer (score 2):

To generate the .coverage file to a specified directory you will have to use **CodeCoverage.exe** with **vstest.console.exe**. Following will be exact command:

```
"%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"%CD%\VisualStudio.coverage" "%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll"
```

Specify the path and name of your coverage file in output parameter above. You don't even have to specify **/EnableCodeCoverage**.

Comment: Unfortunately, all this did for me was copy the coverage file to the output file I specified. :(